# $\log_{10}y = m\log_{10} x + \log_{10} c $ for straight line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Express $x$ in terms of $y$:

[image]

$\log_{10}y = 2\log_{10}x + \log_{10} c$

When $x = 0$

$$2 = \log_{10} c$$

$$c = 100$$

$$\log_{10} y = 2\log_{10}x + \log_{10} c$$

$$\log_{10}y = \log_{10}(x^2c)$$

$$\log_{10}y = \log_{10}(100x^2)$$

$$y = 100x^2$$

But the answer is apparently $y = 10 × 100^x$

Comment: $\log x$ is not defined for $x=0$.

Comment: The axes are labelled $x$ and $\log_{10} y$, so shouldn't you have $\log_{10}y = 2x+c$?

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman yes that is correct.  I missed that

Answer (score 3):

If you observe carefully, equation of the straight line should be: $$\log_{10}y = 2x + c$$
Then at $x=0$, you get $\log_{10}y=1 \Rightarrow y=10$. So we get that $c=1$.

Hence equation of the straight line becomes 
$$\log_{10}y = 2x + 1$$
or, $$y = 10^{2x + 1}=10^{2x}\cdot 10^1=10\cdot 100^{x}$$

Thus, equation of the straight line is $$y=10 \times 100^{x}$$

Hope this helps.